# not knowing how to open a react & firebase website that I created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, livechat

So I just made a website following this toturial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQyrwxMPm88
I followed it and I have the code one to one
but when I looked at the firebase page of mine it doesn't tell me what is the URL of the website that I created so know I am stuck with a website not knowing how to run it or open it
PS. if I need to run some sort of script that I made from the toturial please tell me because I have no Idea

Comment: if anyone is trying to solve it just comment to let me know It just helps my brain knowing that someone is helping me

Comment: are you trying to run it on your own computer? If so, typing the command `npm start` is probably what you need, assuming the tutorial is set up like most projects. After it starts you will probably see a `localhost` url in the log, and it may even open your browser automatically. Or are you saying you've deployed your code and are trying to find out where firebase hosting has put the site on the public internet?

Comment: the second one thank you for your help

Comment: when I do npm start it just showed me this without opening anything: Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

Comment: Line 34:9:   Emojis should be wrapped in <span>, have role="img", and have an accessible description with aria-label or aria-labelledby  jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji
  Line 108:7:  Emojis should be wrapped in <span>, have role="img", and have an accessible description with aria-label or aria-labelledby  jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji Line 122:7:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-tex